# R - splitting a string one character after a space

Tags: r, split

I have postcode data in R that looks like this:

```
Postcodes
AB4 6JK
AR14 8UI
D4 9IK
CB3 9EU
```

But I want to split the postcodes into postcode sectors, which includes everything one character after the space, so that they look like this:

```
Postcodes
AB4 6
AR14 8
D4 9
CB3 9
```

I've found lots of Q&As which focus on separating out strings based on spaces, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38669267/r-splitting-a-column-of-character-separated-by-different-number-of-spaces) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562623/split-an-uneven-character-string-in-r-with-space), but how do I specify to split out one character after the space?

The postcodes are not fixed lengths.

I intend to aggregate the postcode data afterwards based on the higher-level postcode sector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following regex approach using `sub`. It creates a capture group and extracts that from the string.

Assuming your data is called `x`:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="Postcodes
                'AB4 6JK'
                'AR14 8UI'
                'D4 9IK'
                'CB3 9EU'")
```

The approach could be like this:

```
sub("^(.*\\s.).*", "\\1", x$Postcodes)
# [1] "AB4 6"  "AR14 8" "D4 9"   "CB3 9"
```

The pattern is: the beginning of the string (`^`), followed by any characters (`.*`) followed by a space (`\\s`) and one additional character (`.`) - these together make the capture group. Plus, anything that follows is not part of the capture group.

Note that if you have strings with multiple spaces it would do the following:

```
sub("^(.*\\s.).*", "\\1", "abc def 981")
#[1] "abc def 9"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive lookbehind regexp to split after a number that is preceded by a space.

```
strsplit(postcode,"(?<= [0-9])",perl=TRUE)
```

To get the first part of the split string:

```
sapply(strsplit(postcode,"(?<= [0-9])",perl=TRUE),'[[',1)
#[1] "AB4 6"  "AR14 8" "D4 9"   "CB3 9"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
lapply(strsplit(as.character(Postcodes), " "), function(x) paste(x[1], substr(x[2],0,1)))
```

Comment: You can also do it without a loop with this idea, i.e. `paste(gsub('\\s+.*', '', x$Postcodes), substring(gsub('.*\\s+', '', x$Postcodes), 1, 1))`