# R - splitting a string two characters before the end

Tags: r, string, split, character

This is a similar question [to this previous query.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39367608/r-splitting-a-string-one-character-after-a-space/39367774#39367774)

However, this time I want to split the postcodes up two characters before the end of the string. How do I do this please?

For example, I have postcode data in R that looks like this, having had the central space removed:

```
Postcodes
AB46JK
AR148UI
D49IK
CB39EU
```

But I want to split the postcodes into postcode sectors, which now includes everything two characters before the end of the string, so that they look like this:

```
Postcodes
AB46
AR148
D49
CB39
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base R, non-regex solution:

```
substring(postcodes, 1, nchar(postcodes)-2 )
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a non-regex solution.  You can pull out everything in each string from the beginning to 3 from the end using the positions via package *stringr* and `str_sub`.

```
library(stringr)
str_sub(c("AB46JK", "AR148UI", "D49IK", "CB39EU"), 1, -3)

[1] "AB46"  "AR148" "D49"   "CB39"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
gsub("(.*).{2}$","\\1",postcodes)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub`:

```
sub("..$", "", df$Postcodes)
# [1] "AB46"  "AR148" "D49"   "CB39"
```

Or `extract` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% extract(Postcodes, "Postcodes", "(.*)..$")
#  Postcodes
#1      AB46
#2     AR148
#3       D49
#4      CB39
```